# Looping through days of week and outputting in data table in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a calendar. The literature of making a calendar in Angular is very little. I'm a beginner to Angular so I know there is a more efficient way to do this but I'm going with what I got. I want to loop through an array of an arrays that has my date data in it thats called weeks.

I then want to output weeks into a table using *ngFor. I was able to successfully do it but my code repeats 5 times and I figure there is a more cohesive way to do this. This is only for the month of December. Here is my code:

calendar.component.ts

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  currentDate = new Date();
  months : string[] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  days: string[] = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

  currentYear : number; 

  weeks: Array<any> = [
    [
      new Date(2019, 11, 1),
      new Date(2019, 11, 2),
      new Date(2019, 11, 3),
      new Date(2019, 11, 4),
      new Date(2019, 11, 5),
      new Date(2019, 11, 6),
      new Date(2019, 11, 7)],
    [
      new Date(2019, 11, 8),
      new Date(2019, 11, 9),
      new Date(2019, 11, 10),
      new Date(2019, 11, 11),
      new Date(2019, 11, 12),
      new Date(2019, 11, 13),
      new Date(2019, 11, 14),
    ],
    [
      new Date(2019, 11, 15),
      new Date(2019, 11, 16),
      new Date(2019, 11, 17),
      new Date(2019, 11, 18),
      new Date(2019, 11, 19),
      new Date(2019, 11, 20),
      new Date(2019, 11, 21),
    ],
    [
      new Date(2019, 11, 22),
      new Date(2019, 11, 23),
      new Date(2019, 11, 24),
      new Date(2019, 11, 25),
      new Date(2019, 11, 26),
      new Date(2019, 11, 27),
      new Date(2019, 11, 28),
    ],
    [
      new Date(2019, 11, 29),
      new Date(2019, 11, 30),
      new Date(2019, 11, 31),
    ]
  ]


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getMonth() {
    return this.months[this.currentDate.getMonth()];
  }

  getFirstDay() {
    return this.days[this.currentDate.getDay()];
  }

  getYear() {
    return this.currentDate.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

calendar.component.html

```
<h3>{{ getMonth() }} {{ getYear() }}</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let week of weeks[0]; let i = index">
                 {{ days[week.getDay()] }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let week of weeks[0]">
                {{ week.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let week of weeks[1]">
                {{ week.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let week of weeks[2]">
                {{ week.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let week of weeks[3]">
                {{ week.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let week of weeks[4]">
                {{ week.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can you change your table body with this

```
   <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let week of weeks">
            <td *ngFor="let weekDay of week ">
                {{ weekDay.getDate() }}
            </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182428/6139527) you need to change the `<tbody>`. Also you need to change your `<thead>` to:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let day of days">
            {{ day }}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

---

Furthermore, invoking a method from the template is bad practice,

```
<h3>{{ getMonth() }} {{ getYear() }}</h3>
```

would cause the method to be called everytime change detection is triggered. Instead you can assign the *returned* string to a variable and display it on the template.

For eg:

```
monthToDisplay: string;

ngOnInit() {
   this.getMonth();
}

getMonth() {
   this.monthToDisplay = this.months[this.currentDate.getMonth()];
}
```

and on the .html

```
<h3>{{ monthToDisplay }}</h3>
```